# Probability function for calculating conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

**My Problem**:
The random variables X and Y have the simultaneous probability function p<sub>X,Y</sub>(x, y).

| p<sub>X,Y</sub>(x, y) | X = 0 | X = 1 | X = 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y = 0 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| Y = 1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.1 |

What is P(X > 0 | Y = 1) ?

**Answer:**
The answer to this problem should be `2/3`

**My attempt of solving it:**
P(X = 1| Y = 1) = 0.3

P(X = 2| Y = 1) = 0.1
P(X > 0| Y = 1) = P(X = 1| Y = 1) + P(X = 2| Y = 1) = 0.4

**My Question**:
I am clearly getting the wrong answer, I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Why did you multiply this?  No.  The correct calculation is $\Pr(X>0\mid Y=1)=\dfrac{\Pr(X=1,Y=1)+\Pr(X=2,Y=1)}{\Pr(Y=1)} = \dfrac{0.3+0.1}{0.6}=\dfrac{2}{3}$

Comment: Further... you wrote $\Pr(X=1\mid Y=1)=0.3$... no.  That $0.3$ number is the probability that $X$ is $1$ at the same time as $Y=1$... namely $\Pr(X=1,Y=1)$.  This is completely different than $\Pr(X=1\mid Y=1)$ which is $\dfrac{0.3}{0.2+0.3+0.1}=0.5$

Comment: JMoravitz, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not correct, you need to use conditional probability. If you have not seen the following formula before, you should try and find "conditional probability" or "Bayes theorem" on youtube/in a textbook. $P(X>0| Y=1)= \frac{P(X>0 \cap Y=1)}{P(Y=1)}=\frac{0.3+0.1}{0.2+0.3+0.1}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: aristotlefromgreece, thanks!